# 3.5 Adventures with Mind Flayers

Tags: dnd-3.5e

Are there any DnD 3.5 adventures that revolve around the illithid? Google hasn't returned anything useful... They're one of my favorite monsters and I'm trying to get a feel them.

Thanks!

Comment: Worth noting are the Mindflayers of Thoon. Not a module (what I'm referring to at least - one probably exists) but there are enough baddies in the pile to make one easily. Monster Manual Five, I believe it is.

Comment: The StarDock comes to mind.

Answer (score 4):

The best [illithid](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Illithid) source is probably from 2e, there is an entire mind flayer sourcebook called the [**Illithiad**](http://www.tsrindex.net/ma/ma-i.htm) with a linked series of three "Monstrous Arcana" adventures published to use with it - [A Darkness Gathering](http://index.rpg.net/display-entry.phtml?mainid=8605), Masters of Eternal Night, and Dawn of the Overmind.

In 3.5e there is an aberration sourcebook called [**Lords of Madness**](http://www.rpg.net/reviews/archive/11/11917.phtml) with a large chapter on the illithids. It has a small adventure in that chapter IIRC.

Answer (score 3):

There is a 3.0 module called the Speaker in Dreams which includes an illithid foe, but he's sort of a renegade and there aren't any others in the module as I recall.  I'm not aware of any 3.5 modules that focus on them, however.  Every module that we played other than Speaker in Dreams during our 3/3.5 time was from converted 2nd edition modules.

Comment: Was taught on that one, it was awesome. Became tradition even to initiate new players. +1

Answer (score 3):

There's a great 3.5E short adventure called [Teleport Gone Awry](http://web.archive.org/web/20100118180453/http://wizards.com/DnD/Article.aspx?x=dnd/duad/20080107) in Dungeon #153. Basically a hook for what happens when adventurers fail a teleport roll and end up in an underground Illithids' model of the city they meant to 'port to. Could be a great intro to the brain eaters.

Comment: I've ran this one; to clarify it's a small surveillance party of Thoon Mind-Flayers which are meant to be slightly different than normal ones (although I ran it to just be normal Illithids). It was a great side-trek and easily spun off into a greater side quest. Very simple and short but gets the point across.